# Organizing Algebraic Expressions (for $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ conversion)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, latex

I would ideally like to not have to spend a lot of time writing LaTeX for complicated algebraic expressions that I've worked out in Mathematica. I know that I can "copy-as-LaTeX", but my current issue is that my algebraic expressions are often formatted slightly wrong.

(Additionally, any general tips for working between $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ and *Mathematica* would be appreciated!)

EDIT:
Explicitly showing the code:

```
expression = -p12 β - 1/2 I (2 p12 (Δc - Δp) - p42 Ωa + p13 Ωc - p32 Ωp + p14 Ωs)
```

For example for the following algebraic expression:

I would like it to be sorted by variables in the following order (p12, p13, p14, p32, p42):

To look like:

$
(-\beta - i (\text{$\Delta $c}-\text{$\Delta $p}))\text{p12}+\text{$\Omega $c} \text{p13} +\text{$\Omega $s} \text{p14} - \text{$\Omega $p} \text{p32}-\text{$\Omega $a} \text{p42}
$

If I use this code:

```
Collect[expression, {p12, p13, p14, p32, p42}]
```

it doesn't seem to organize the variables in this order (of `{p12, p13, p14, p32, p42}`). instead, it returns an ordering:

[image]

Additionally...I've observed that if I copy-as latex, what is above appears. But if I look at what I am copying, it has this form:

$\text{p12} (-\beta +i (\text{$\Delta $p}-\text{$\Delta $c}))-\frac{i \text{p13} \text{$\Omega $c}}{2}-\frac{i \text{p14} \text{$\Omega $s}}{2}+\frac{i \text{p32} \text{$\Omega $p}}{2}+\frac{i \text{p42} \text{$\Omega $a}}{2}$

Comment: Could you give an example of how `Collect` gives the "wrong" parsing of an equation?

Comment: [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) is [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I added the example for me, but it's a bit strange. What I see it returning as an output appears to be sorted incorrectly, but when I copy it as latex, it actually gives me the correct order!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I added code that can be copy-pasted.

Comment: Does `TraditionForm[result]` give you what you want? -- Why does the order matter? Is it for output-formatting purposes (for a report or paper)?  Or is it for some further computation you wish to perform on it?

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the comment, `Plus` is orderless. To solve this problem, one may replace `Plus` by another function, say `plus`, and define the format for `plus`. For example,

`Format[plus[x__]]:=HoldForm[Plus[x]];
var={p12, p13, p14, p32, p42};
SortBy[plus@@Collect[expression,var],Cases[#,Alternatives@@var,{0,Infinity}]&]//TeXForm`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
MonomialList[expression, 
     {p12, p13, p14, p32, p42}] /. 
   {args__} :> HoldForm[Plus[args]]
```

[image]

`TraditionalForm[expression]` shows the monomials in the same order, but I think it's merely a coincidence.

You have to hold `Plus` to keep the arguments from being reordered, just as @Wen Chern has done, too.  This sort of manipulation is usually only done for the purposes of presenting output in a more human-readable form. It is not usually a convenient way to compute with expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I also need the variables to be to the right of the coefficients. Is that also doable?